# Datatables: how to load data into grid when user clicks on a tab based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

So I'm working on a website using the DataTables API, which hosts information on troubleshooting videos. There are all status, approved, certified, and rejected video status tabs on my data table that allow you to navigate through videos with varying statuses.

For efficiency, I'm passing in one "All Videos" JSON object instead of passing in a JSON object for each category of vidoes. So what I'm trying to do is filter through the first column, which is status, on my "All Videos" table and find the status I'm looking for. For example, when you hit the "Approved" tab, I want to display all table rows where GRID.column(0).data() == "Approved".

Here's the code I have in the pageSetUp() function:

```
     $("#VideoReviewTabs li").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#VideoReviewTabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        loadSelectedList($(this).data("listname"));
    });
```

And here's the loadApprovedVideosTab() function:

```
    function loadApprovedVideosTab() {
       var GRID = $("#VIDEO_GRID").DataTable();
       var typeCol = GRID.column(0).data();
       GRID.column(0).data().filter(function (value, index) {
        return value == "Approved" ? true : false;
       });
    }
```

This filter function is definitely not working and selecting the various tabs does nothing to the table grid. The loadApprovedVideosTab() function does get called, but the filtering obviously doesn't work.

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your function doesn't return anything... try

```
function filterApprovedVideosTab() {
   var GRID = $("#VIDEO_GRID").DataTable();
   // var typeCol = GRID.column(0).data();

   return GRID.column(0).data().filter(function (value, index) {
    return value == "Approved" ? true : false;
   });
}

var approved = filterApprovedVideosTab();
```

Comment: loadSelectedList() function in the first code snippet is a function that calls loadApprovedVideosTab(). It's getting called, but not populating the grid.

Comment: So you need to redraw your table

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `Approved` videos you can use the function `search` on the correspond column, then call draw upon it:

```
function loadApprovedVideosTab() {
   var GRID = $("#VIDEO_GRID").DataTable();
   GRID.column(0).search('Approved').draw();
}
```

[Reference.](http://datatables.net/reference/api/search())